# Installing CUDA as a non-root user with no GPU

Tags: cuda, installation, development-environment, gpgpu

I have a desktop without a GPU, on which I would like to develop code; and a machine on some cluster which has a GPU, and CUDA installed, but where I really can't "touch" anything and on which I won't run an IDE etc. I don't have root on any of the machines, woe is me.

So, essentially, I want to be able to compile and build my CUDA code on my own GPU-less desktop machine, then just copy it and test it on the other machine.

Can this be done despite the two hindering factors: I seem to recall the CUDA installer requiring the presence of a GPU; playing with the kernel; and doing other root-y stuff.

**Notes:**

- I'll be using the standalone installer, not a package.
- I'm on Fedora 22 with an x86_64 CPU.

Comment: You don't need to install the driver to install the Linux toolkit. Whether fedora 22 is supported, I don't know.

Comment: Fedora 22 or 23 are not officially supported, as well as GCC 5, which is a default compiler there. There is a [workaround](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Install-NVIDIA-CUDA-on-Fedora-22-with-gcc-5-1-654/), but it still fails in mixed CUDA/C++ code because of C++ standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Assuming you want to develop codes that use the **CUDA runtime API**, you can install the cuda toolkit on a system that does not have a GPU.  Using the [runfile installer method](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile), simply answer no when prompted to install the driver.
2. If you want to compile codes (successfully) that use the **CUDA driver API**, that process will require a libcuda.so on your machine.  This file is installed by the driver installer.  There are various methods to "force" the driver installer to run on a machine without a GPU.  You can get started by extracting the driver runfile installer (or downloading it separately) and passing the `--help` command line switch to the installer to learn about some of the options.
3. These methods will not allow you to run those codes on a machine with no GPU of course.  Furthermore, the process of moving a compiled binary from one machine to another, and expecting it to run correctly, is troublesome in my opinion.  Therefore my suggestion would be to re-compile the code on a target machine.  Otherwise getting a compiled binary to run from one machine to the next is a question that is not unique to CUDA, and is outside the scope of my answer.
4. If you have no intention of running the codes on the non-GPU machine, and are willing to recompile on the target machine, then you can probably develop driver API codes even without libcuda.so (or there is a libcuda.so stub that you could try linking against just for compilation-test purposes, which is installed by the CUDA installer, if you search for it: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs).  If you don't link your driver API code against `-lcuda`, then you'll get a link error of course, but it should not matter, given the previously stated caveats.
5. Fedora 22 is [not officially supported](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#system-requirements) by CUDA 7.5 or prior.  YMMV.
6. If you don't run the driver installer, you don't need to be a root user for any of this.  Of course the install locations you pass to the installer must be those that your user privilege allows access to.

Comment: Actually I don't mind having to build on the other machine - but then I'll only be building once rather than hitting compilation errors when I write something new.